# Instagram API restrictions

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram API has limit for 5000 calls per hour. Some instagram analytics services (for example https://smartmetrics.co ) allow to analyze multiple accounts at same time. I've analyzed multiple accounts with total followers 200k and smartmetrics done it with 3 hours and results looks true. How can it be possible? Is any way to increase limit for API calls?

Comment: Generally the API limits are relatively rigid, but you can always try contacting instagram to see if you can get an API rate increase for your application.

Comment: @EliSadoff thank you

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what API they using to analyze, you can get up to 50 followers data with one API call, so 200K followers will take 4000 API calls and can be done with the one hour.

If they are analyzing more details and posts of individual follower, then they have to make an API call for every follower.